# GSON Deserialize Map of Custom Object

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I am trying to deserialize a Map<EventContext.Key, Object> using GSON.

I initially tried to deserialize by

```
    System.out.println(eventContextMapSerialized);
    Map<EventContext.Key, Object> deserializedMap = gson.fromJson(eventContextMapSerialized, HashMap.class);
    LogisticService logisticService = (LogisticService) deserializedMap.get(EventContext.Key.LOGISTIC_SERVICE);
    System.out.println(deserializedMap.get(EventContext.Key.LOGISTIC_SERVICE));
    System.out.println(logisticService);
```

This gave me the output

```
[junit] {"LOGISTIC_SERVICE":{"serviceId":"dummy_id","serviceVersion":1,"serviceProviderRefId":{"id":"dummy_id"},"contract":{"invoiceCreator":"USPS","maxDaysToReceiveInvoice":180},"cancelled":false,"serviceConsumer":{"id":"SERVICE_CONSUMER_ID_1"},"serviceProvider":{"id":"USPS"},"plannedServiceTimePeriod":{"startTime":"Jan 1, 1970 5:30:00 AM"},"planner":"ATROPS"},"PLATFORM_SERVICE_ID":"TestPlatformServiceId"}
[junit] null
[junit] null
```

So, even though the serialized string contains object of type LogisticService, when I try to fetch it, I get null.

Hence, I tried to use the overloaded method of `fromJson` which takes a Type as an argument.

```
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<EventContext.Key, Object>>(){}.getType();
    Map<EventContext.Key, Object> eventContextMapDeserialized = gson.fromJson(eventContextMapSerialized, type);
    System.out.println("Event Context Map Deserialized is : " + eventContextMapDeserialized);

    System.out.println(eventContextMapDeserialized.get(EventContext.Key.LOGISTIC_SERVICE).getClass());
    LogisticService logisticServiceFromMap = (LogisticService) eventContextMapDeserialized.get(EventContext.Key.LOGISTIC_SERVICE);
    System.out.println("Logistic Service from Event Context Map : " + logisticServiceFromMap);
    System.out.println("Direct Logistic Service : " + eventContextDeserialized.get(EventContext.Key.LOGISTIC_SERVICE));
```

which gave the output,

```
[junit] Event Context Map Deserialized is : {LOGISTIC_SERVICE={serviceId=dummy_id, serviceVersion=1.0, serviceProviderRefId={id=dummy_id}, contract={invoiceCreator=USPS, maxDaysToReceiveInvoice=180.0}, cancelled=false, serviceConsumer={id=SERVICE_CONSUMER_ID_1}, serviceProvider={id=USPS}, plannedServiceTimePeriod={startTime=Jan 1, 1970 5:30:00 AM}, planner=ATROPS}, PLATFORM_SERVICE_ID=TestPlatformServiceId}
[junit] class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap
[junit] Testcase: testPayloadDeserialize took 10.812 sec
[junit]     Caused an ERROR
[junit] com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.amazon.transportation.tfs.contapservice.sdk.model.LogisticService
[junit] java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.amazon.transportation.tfs.contapservice.sdk.model.LogisticService
```

Basically, blowing up where I try to cast

`(LogisticService) eventContextMapDeserialized.get(EventContext.Key.LOGISTIC_SERVICE);`

I am not able to figure out why in 1st case output is Null and in 2nd case even after giving the type, it is still crashing.

Comment: In your 2nd snippet, you've told Gson to interpret the JSON as `Object`. How do you think it should know that it should actually deserialize into a `LogisticService`?

Comment: @Savior The map we have is of type Map<EventContext.Key, Object>.

Comment: Right, so it knows how to deserialize the JSON names as `Key` objects. But all it knows about the values is that they should be `Object`.

Comment: @Savior We have another piece of code where the same Map is being deserialized and I am able to fetch the object from it and cast it into `LogisticService`
Only difference is we are using Jackson serializer there compared to GSON in this case.

Comment: I don't believe it. By the way, the first case output is `null`, because the name in the JSON is deserialized as a Java `String` (the key of the map).

Comment: It's weird that you're using 2 different JSON parsers. If (you think) it works with Jackson, use Jackson.

Comment: We are trying to migrate everything to GSON.

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you then. The reasons are in my previous comments. With `HashMap.class`, Gson has to guess what types to store. For JSON strings, it uses Java Strings. For JSON objects, it uses `LinkedTreeMap`. With the `TypeToken` and `Object`, it again has to guess. For JSON objects, it again uses `LinkedTreeMap`. If you can't provide a custom class and have to use a `Map`, consider writing a custom deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, when you deserialize `HashMap.class` or `TypeToken<Map<EventContext.Key, Object>>` Gson cannot know which value types you expect. Instead it sees that the data contains a JSON object and deserializes it as Java `Map` by default (Gson's internal `Map` implementation is `LinkedTreeMap`).

Since it looks like you are dealing with a heterogenous map you need to take an alternative approach. The following solutions all have their advantages and disadvantages and it depends on your use case which one fits best.

#### Separate model class

You could create a separate class to model the `Map`, e.g.:

```java
class EventData {
    // Use Gson's @SerializedName annotation to not use the field name
    @SerializedName("LOGISTIC_SERVICE")
    public LogisticService logisticService;
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
EventData eventData = gson.fromJson(EventData.class);
LogisticService logisticService = eventData.logisticService;
```

This solution is probably the easiest one. The disadvantage is that you cannot preserve any JSON object members which are not part modelled as fields of your model class.

#### Parsing to DOM, then parsing desired member

You could first deserialize the JSON data as a [`JsonObject`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html), which is Gson's class representing the JSON document tree. This can for example be done with [`JsonParser`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html). Afterwards you use `JsonObject.getAsJsonObject(String)` to extract the relevant member and deserialize it with `Gson.fromJson(JsonElement, ...)`.

The advantage is that this allows you to access other members from that `JsonObject` as well, for example if they are needed at a later stage. However, the disadvantage is that this requires more memory because it has to hold the complete JSON document as `JsonObject` in memory, but depending on your use case or your data that might be negligible.

#### Using `JsonReader`

One solution could be to directly use a [`JsonReader`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html) and then depending on the JSON object member names parse them respectively:

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
LogisticService logisticService = null;

JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(json);
jsonReader.beginObject();
while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
    String name = jsonReader.nextName();
    if (name.equals(EventContext.Key.LOGISTIC_SERVICE.name()) {
        if (logisticService != null) {
            // Duplicate member -> malicious or malformed JSON, throw exception
            ...
        }
        logisticService = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, LogisticService.class);
    }
    else {
        // Skip value or parse it in a different way
        jsonReader.skipValue();
    }
}
jsonReader.endObject();
```

Or when this data is part of a larger JSON document you can also put this code into a [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) and create the `Gson` instance using a `GsonBuilder` on which you [registered](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapterFactory(com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory)) the factory.