# ClassCastException: Object turning into Google Gson LinkedTreeMap

Tags: java, gson, classcastexception

I have a User class, where all data about a unique `User` is stored.

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private Map<String, Object> extras;
    // other fields

    public Map<String, Object> getExtras() {
        if (extras == null) extras = new HashMap<>();
        return extras;
    }
}
```

In `extras`, I have stored an instance of `OrderProfile`, but it is stored as an `Object` type.

I have this method to get the `OrderProfile` object inside the `OrderProfile` class:

```java
public static OrderProfile get(@NotNull User user) {
    if (!user.getExtras().containsKey("orderProfile")) return null;
    return (OrderProfile) user.getExtras().get("orderProfile");
}
```

However, when I attempt to get the object from the `extras` map, I get the following error:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to class net.pixlies.business.market.orders.OrderProfile (com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @759ebb3d; net.pixlies.business.market.orders.OrderProfile is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @26b5e81e)`

I haven't stored anything as a LinkedTreeMap, so I don't know why this is happening.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: How would GSON know to create an `OrderProfile`?

Comment: @shmosel Oh, I don't know. How can I "tell" GSON how to create an `OrderProfile`?

Comment: Your best bet is to use a real `class Extras { OrderProfile orderProfile; }`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65013074/1553851) for some alternatives.